# Questions about servers, databases, and android

Tags: java, android, sql, networking

Ok so I'm trying to develop a server for an android app that I'm developing.

Basically it's an application that needs to connect with other phones through a database system.

I was thinking of using an sql database to store the simple data I need to exchange.

What type of server should I be using?

What language should I be writing the database code in (if besides SQL)?

How do I get the android application to communicate and exchange information with the database?

Is there a type of virtual server I can use to test my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server type and language choices very much depend on your skillset and environment. However, I'd suggest exposing queries to your database either through JSON or XML, and presenting through a web server.

PHP & MySQL are as good a choice as any, as you can run the same code on UNIX, Linux, Solaris, or MacOS servers. Of course, using a J2EE environment with JDBC drivers to a generic server is also a good choice, especially if you need to share any classes between Android and your server.

By 'virtual server' I assume you mean 'virtual handset', in which case the Android emulator in the SDK might be good enough (although it is painfully slow), or just use a real Android device plugged in to your development machine.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello